# Context of Array() in this function

Tags: javascript, arrays, jasmine

```
  it("should know properties that are functions act like methods", function() {
    var meglomaniac = { 
      mastermind : "Brain", 
      henchman: "Pinky",
      battleCry: function(noOfBrains) {
        return "They are " + this.henchman + " and the" +
          Array(noOfBrains + 1).join(" " + this.mastermind);
      }
    };

    var battleCry = meglomaniac.battleCry(4);
    expect('They are Pinky and the Brain Brain Brain Brain').toMatch(battleCry);
  });
```

What is the definition of Array in this code (line 7)? I looked it up and it looks like it's an Array.of() command which generates an empty array of length n which in this case would be 5? So why does it end up with only 4 brain inputs assuming that is the correct assumption? Or is this array() doing something else?

Comment: Not `Array.of`. It's the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) (used as a plain function, ie no `new`). See the notes here about the difference ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`battleCry(4)` means that `Array(noOfBrains + 1)` will indeed have a length of 5:

```
[empty, empty empty, empty, empty]
```

But when you `.join` those 5 elements, you only insert something into the *spaces between* them, and there are only 4 spaces:

```
[empty, empty empty, empty, empty]
//     ^     ^      ^      ^
```

So, you end up with 4 occurrences of `this.mastermind` in the resulting string.

This code is quite confusing. I'd strongly prefer something like `.repeat` instead:

```js
var meglomaniac = { 
  mastermind : " Brain", 
  henchman: "Pinky",
  battleCry: function(noOfBrains) {
    return `They are ${this.henchman} and the${this.mastermind.repeat(noOfBrains)}`
  }
};

var battleCry = meglomaniac.battleCry(4);
console.log(battleCry === 'They are Pinky and the Brain Brain Brain Brain');
```

`Array` is just the array constructor. It's not really anything special, it just creates an array which has a `length` of the parameter (when passed a number).

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a bit confused - and this is an exercise from Javascript Koans I am trying to understand. From what I know: I normally use Array.join()  where it concatenates all the array elements into a string. In this instance. The newly formed array of 5 has a length of 5 with no defined values in them. Why does .join work to add in the value of this.mastermind? From the notation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join. I see no possible reasoning for this behavior nor have I seen it before this code.

Comment: I think I get it now. Per syntax of .join: `arr.join([separator])`. Everything inside the () is the separator:  `.join(" " + this.mastermind)`. I have only been so used to separating arrays by spaces or commas that it never occurred to me that you could also actually add valid strings of words which it adds `this.mastermind` along with the space between each array element. Is that the correct logic behind this?

Comment: Yes, the argument passed to `.join` is the separator by which the elements from index 0 to `length - 1` of the array are joined. In this case, there are no such elements, so you can consider them to be like empty strings when `.join`ed.

Comment: Gotcha. One last question. If I make an array of length 5 in this case, and don't put anything in it. Every element in the array is undefined? So how are you able to run this `undefined + "  " + "Brain"`. As in how does the complier add `undefined`?

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis Check the notes in the `Array.prototype.join()` documentation ~ [_"If an element is `undefined`, `null` or an empty array `[]`, it is converted to an empty string."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Description)

Comment: Ah. Thank you @Phil. Good to know!

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis The array doesn't actually contain `undefined` elements - the array only has an own property of `.length`, actually (which is very strange, and is one reason why I prefer to avoid the array constructor). But regardless, the behavior is the same as if they were undefined - they turn into the empty string when used with `.join`.

Comment: Okay. Well now I'm even more confused. Looking at the documentation. You are correct. How can an array have a defined length but have no defined elements inside?? I assume when Array(5) executes, it generates an array of a length of 5 in memory. What is exactly in that array then? There must be something 'defined' in the array for it to say that it can hold 5 elements

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis It's called a "sparse array" - one whose `.length` does not match the number of own-properties which are array indicies. Best to always avoid them. Here, the array does not have any array-index properties, just a `.length` of 5 - but `.join` will iterate over all indicies from `0` to `length - 1`, *whether or not those properties actually exist on the array*. Accessing them returns `undefined`, which, when put into the string for `.join`, become the empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your help @CertainPerformance! I have even more questions about this now, but I will leave it alone as this seems like a bit of a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to manually add 1 to the number of elements in the Array to overcome the problem, by using `Array.fill()`.

```
Array(4).fill("Brain").join(" ");   // have an array of 4 elements,
                                    // fill each vacant spot with "Brain"
                                    // and flatten it by separating elements
                                    // by a space
//Brain Brain Brain Brain
```

So your code can be simplified as:

```
Array(noOfBrains).fill(this.mastermind).join(" ");
```